# Rain and Splash Effects I can't see type fluid why?

Tags: fluid-simulation, properties

I can't see the same properties types than on the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35bbyAJodEQ 11:38 is it normal on the last blender version and how I can add this property on the domain cube, the bottom fluid and the fluid sphere? thank you for your help !!! :D

Comment: what version of blender are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am on 2.8 I downloaded 1 month ago

Comment: Try updating to the latest version and reset to factory settings

Comment: It already what I did but what I am talking about it the version in the video which is the previous version and now the settings are different